# Read text files and write it to excel in java

Tags: java, excel, text

I have to read a text file and write it to an already existing excel file. The excel file is a customized excel sheet with different items in different columns. The items has different values for each of them... These items with there value can be found in a text file. But i dont have much idea as to how to do this.

E.g- example.txt

Name: John

Age=24

Sex=M

Graduate=M.S

example.xlsx

Age:           Sex:

Name:          Graduate:

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: there is a library called jxl(java excel) for this `http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/`

Answer (score 4):

Just as for so many other problems that need solved, there's an Apache library for that! In this case, it's the [POI library](http://poi.apache.org/). I've only used it for very basic spreadsheet manipulation, but managed that by just following a few tutorials. I'd link to one, but I can't now remember where it was.

Comment: i have used POI apache earlier to write a hard coded value to a specific cell. But i have no clue as to how the code will read the value for a specific item n place that value to the specific cell in excel...

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Apache POI-HSSF library](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) for reading and writing Excel files with Java. There are some [quick guides](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) to get you started.

This post [How to read and write excel file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java?rq=1) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a *.csv (comma separated value) file in Java. Just create a simple text file with CSV extension and put your values in there like that :

Age:,24,Sex:,M,

So you just separate your values with commas (or other delimiters like ';').
Every line in this file is a row, and every delimiter separates two columns. You won't be able to add colours/styles/formatting this way, but it gives you a file that is openable and understandable even without Excel (or other spreadsheet software).

Comment: thanks very much buddy...but my problem is that i have been asked to use excel only...