# How can I read Excel file in Java?

Tags: java, xml, excel, xls, xlsx

How can I read Excel file in Java in XML format like below?

If I'm trying

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
```

then I getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x726576206C6D783C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0
```

If I'm trying

```
XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
```

then I getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
```

Excel file:

```xml
<xml version>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-    microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
 <Styles>
 <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
 <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
 <Borders/>
 <Font/>
 <Interior/>
 <NumberFormat/>
 <Protection/>
 </Style>
 <Style ss:ID="BoldColumn">
 <Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
 </Style>
 <Style     ss:ID="StringLiteral">
 <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
 </Style>
 <Style ss:ID="Decimal">
 <NumberFormat ss:Format="0.0000"/>
 </Style>
 <Style ss:ID="Integer">
 <NumberFormat ss:Format="0"/>
 </Style>
 <Style ss:ID="DateLiteral">
 <NumberFormat ss:Format="mm/dd/yyyy;@"/>
 </Style>
```

Many thanks for any help.
Mik

Comment: The invalid header exception is usually a sign of corrupted file or that the file isn't a Excel file.

Comment: Consider using [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), you can find tutorial [here](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html).

Comment: Also, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java

Comment: BTW. My file is large. Over 150 MB

Answer (score 1):

XSSF expects an actual ZIP file with the components.  The error relates to the fact that the OPC format requires a file `[Content_Types].xml`.

One solution is to take an existing XLSX file, unzip it, replace the file `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml` and then re-zip.