# Convert string to xls - Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Well, I have a String in my project that is like this:

```
,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
,0,0,0,7,8,6,6,
,3,3,3,3,9,4,5,
,5,6,6,9,5,2,1,
,6,2,8,0,0,3,9,
--------------------------------------------------
Reference,-,C,A,A,G,A,T,
17-F1,.,.,.,.,.,T,C,
37-F2,1A,A,C,T,T,.,.,
```

And I need to convert this to a XLS file

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java) may be helpful.

Comment: The thing is, this string is kinda a csv file, so which word supposed to be in one cell, so i'm having trouble thinking how to read the "line" and put those words into cells

Comment: Can't you just do `str.split(",")` to split your string by commas and then each element in the resulting array will go in a cell? I'm having trouble understanding what exactly is part of the string. Is it the numbers above ---- or everything.

Comment: I can do that, but this is one big string, and I need to split those lines too. If i do that the string will be in only one line.

Comment: Ah I see, so there aren't newlines then. Do you know the number of columns? In that case you could still split it and then every Nth element let's say would be the beginning of the next row.

Comment: It isnt the same number every time :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My awnser using Apache poi and Commons IO

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(new StringReader(csv));

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String str[] = lines.get(i).split(",");
        Row row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
             row.createCell(j).setCellValue(helper.createRichTextString(str[j]));

                 }
              }

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:\\someName.xls");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```