# Use data from excel sheet to populate web text fields, submit page, repeat?

Tags: java, python, c++

I have an excel sheet full of personal information such as name, birthday, height, etc for around 60 people. I have to manually input all of this data into a site one person at a time, hit submit, and repeat this 60 times. Is there a way to automate this process? I'm familiar with python, java, and c++.

Comment: Learn here in java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java

Answer (score 0):

(1) Do Save as CSV (comma,semicolon, pipe seperated) file. Now you can easily read the file using python, python pandas library.
(2) Use python pandas library to read excel file.
    Learn here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Now dump your data in database using python or java servlet.
   Access the database whenever or whereever you want in your site.