# How can I read, write and create an excel file using java?

Tags: java, excel, file-io, io

I am aiming to only use the java API in order to accomplish this. I know that for other languages such as c and matlab, there are specific functions/methods that can do this. However, I'm unable to find a specific class in the java API that may help me complete my task. I am simply aiming to read from one excel file and using some of the information in the file I am trying to create another excel file after analyzing some of its data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) .Specifically the [HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) module. A [quick guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) is there.
And this is a past discussion on this topic.
[How to read and write excel file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java)

Comment: I'm aiming to only use the java API though. Using Apache POI would force me to use that API.

Comment: In order to do this with "only" the Java API, you would have to read the file in the raw, and interpret its format with your own Java code. Be prepared to spend many months figuring it out. I don't know if the format is published anywhere, it would not surprise me if it is not. Your 'goal' to use only the Java API is strange, practically nothing significant anywhere is developed these days without some kind of library.