# How to import a .xls file to mysql Database using java?

Tags: java, mysql, excel, csv

I'm trying to upload an Excel file `.xls` to my MySQL Database using Java NetBeans but I didn't find any solution.

I tried with CSV file and it worked fine, but I would still like to use the `.xls` file format.

To achieve this I want the user to click a `JButton` in my `JFrame`, choose an Excel file by using `JFileChooser` and then save that file in my database.

Following is the image of what I currently have:
[image: JFrame image]

And this is the code I used so far:

```
private void importer_csv_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
    import_interne_txt.setText(filename);

    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] value = line.split(",");
            String sql = "INSERT INTO Interne(Matricule,Nom,Prénom,Sexe,Date_naissance,Nationalité,Lieu_naissance,Willaya,Email,Moyenne1,Moyenne2,Redoublement,Conseil,Num_Phone,Password,CPI_Code) " + "VALUES('" + value[0] + "','" + value[1] + "','" + value[2] + "','" + value[3] + "','" + value[4] + "','" + value[5] + "','" + value[6] + "','" + value[7] + "','" + value[8] + "','" + value[9] + "','" + value[10] + "','" + value[11] + "','" + value[12] + "','" + value[13] + "','" + value[14] + "','" + value[15] + "')";
            pst = Con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeUpdate();

        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    Update_table();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read and write excel file in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache POI to read data from xls files.

Example:

```
public extractDataFromXls(String fileName, sheetName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        HSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(0);
        for (short i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i);
            String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe some piece of code to show its use? Link-only answers are discouraged here.

Comment: how to use your code in jbutton for visibling  Jfilechooser and choosing the xls file