# How to use xls csv files as source in javafx charts

Tags: java, csv, javafx, charts, xls

I am newbie in java, am looking for a code to build charts and tables in `javafx` using local xls and csv files as a source.

csv file first 3 lines look like :

```
N° tournée";"Secteur géographique";"N° contrat";"Libellé catégorie facturation";"Libellé Code Relève";"Ann Trn";"Per Trn";"N° facture";"Mois Actif - Montant TTC de la facture ";"Montant restant dû";"Montant TTC Facture Avoir";"Volume facturé";"Libellé Type Origine";"Libellé traité principal";"Libellé type abonnement";"Libellé type utilisation";"Code état abonnement";"Mois Precendent - Montant facturé";"Mois Precendent - Vol  facturé";"Anne Precedente - Montant TTC de la facture";"Anne Precedente - Vol Cso Facturé";"Type Sect";"Règlement";"Mode de facturation";"Ecart M-Actif vs M-Precedent (Mnt)";"Ecart M-Actif vs A-Precedente (Mnt)";"Ecart M-Actif vs M-Precedent (Vol)";"Ecart M-Actif vs A-Precedente (Vol)";"Plage M-Actif";"Plage Vol M-Precedent";"Plage Ecart M-Actif vs M-Precedent  10%";"Plage Ecart M-Actif vs A-Precedente 10%";"Plage Ecart M-Actif vs M-Precedent  20%";"Plage Ecart M-Actif vs A-Precedente 20%";"Tranches M-Precedent";"Tranches M-Actif";"Tranches A-Precedente"
58;5201;47335;"BT ECLAIRAGE PRIVE";"RELEVE SANS ANOMALIE";2016;4;20161043484411;30,42;0;"";0;"INDEX RELEVE NORMALE";"TETOUAN BT";"PARTICULIER";"ECLAIRAGE";"SE";31,32;1;31,32;1;NA;"Reglé";"Facturation Progressive";-3;-3;-100;-100;"inf ou egal a 184";"Sup a 0";"Inf ou egal a 10%";"Inf ou egal a 10%";"Inf ou egal a 20%";"Inf ou egal a 20%";"TR1";"TR1";"TR1"
58;5208;47336;"BT ECLAIRAGE PRIVE";"RELEVE SANS ANOMALIE";2016;4;20161043930126;30,42;30,42;"";0;"INDEX RELEVE NORMALE";"TETOUAN BT";"PARTICULIER";"ECLAIRAGE";"SE";30,42;0;30,42;0;NA;NA;"Facturation Progressive";0;0;NA;NA;"inf ou egal a 184";"Inf ou egal a 0";"Inf ou egal a 10%";"Inf ou egal a 10%";"Inf ou egal a 20%";"Inf ou egal a 20%";"TR1";"TR1";"TR1"
```

xls file is a simple table like :

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: This is partially a duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java) and the rest is certainly too broad.

Comment: This 2 subjects doesn't help, up.