# How to read excel file in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I am making a desktop app using `ember.js` and `electron`. I need to read data from excel file.

Can anyone give me simple code snippet for this? Are there any external libraries for this purpose?

Comment: Edited, now no difference between this question and [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx). Add it as bower dependecy and add its imports to your `ember-cli-build` file as:

```
app.import('bower_components/js-xlsx/dist/jszip.js');
app.import('bower_components/js-xlsx/dist/xlsx.min.js');
```

Handle it as the documentation's [parsing-workbooks](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx#parsing-workbooks) section shows. (`handleFile` function is explaining it well.)