# What is the best way to read and write data from excel using java?

Tags: java, excel

I am currently developing an app using java, the main aim is to read some data from excel to do some operations on them and write it to a new excel file. Actually I have did some research to find the best way, I have seen some people using POI and some others are using APIs. What you guys recommend for that?
Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree , POI its an excelent option
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_java_excel.htm

Answer (score 0):

i used POI in my solution, it is strong and powerful. more choice please refer to : 
[How to read and write excel file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I have used both Apache POI and JXL. However, I prefer Apache POI, because it has everything you'll ever need while handling Excel files, **no matter which version** either 2003 or 2007 formats. The strength and flexibility are amazing.