# Best API to read/write EXCEL documents with spring mvc

Tags: excel, api, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am developing a web application with spring-mvc, hibernate and MySQL.
I need to :

1. export data from Database table to an EXCEL document.
2. import an excel file , read data, and insert this data in my Database (MySQL).

In the two case, I am using a large sized excel files with .xls or .xlsx format.

Can you help me to find the best API TO READ/WRITE EXCEL files (Apache poi ,JExcel ,....).
And if there are some tutorial dedicated to this need.

I just want to know witch API should i use **Apache poi** or **JExcel** and if there is other API and why?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read and write excel file in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java)

Comment: I  just want to know witch API should i use Apache poi or JExcel and if there is other API and why?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to process both .xlsx and .xls files than Apache poi is better because Jexcel supports only .xls files. There are other libraries like xlsx4j which supports only .xlsx files. Based on my experience (not opinion, I have worked with all of them) Apache poi has pretty good documentation and a lot of examples/tutorials so it's easier to use. Also support of the both types (.xlsx and .xls) is a huge advantage.

Comment: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say 
"Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers