# How to use python to read excel column data and print column duplicates

Tags: python

Two columns  ("Name" & "Value") in excel.

There are duplicates (eg. "xxa","xxf") in the Value column and the python script needs to find what are the duplicates cell values and put them into an array

[image]

The output should be

```py
{
  "xxa": ["aaa","bbb","ccc","hhh"],
  "xxf": ["fff","jjj"]
}
```

How to improve the current script?

```
file = open('columnData.csv')
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
next(csvreader)

for row in csvreader:
    name = row[0]
    value = row[1]
    value_col.append(value)
    name_value_col.append(name+","+value)
file.close()
count={}
names=[]

for item in value_col:
    if value_col.count(item)>1:
        count[item]=value_col.count(item)

for name,value in count.items():
    names.append(name) 
total=[]

for item in name_value_col:
    item_name=item.split(",")     
    if item_name[1] in names:  
        total.append(item_name[0])
print(total)
```

Comment: upload the csv as text please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read and write excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file)

Comment: I need to find the duplicates as well

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `defaultdict`, and while you're at it using `csv.DictReader` makes for more legible code:

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
with open('columnData.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        data[row['Value']].append(row['Name'])
```

and then regarding duplicate finding you can EITHER take the destructive approach (pruning non-duplicates)

```py
# Remove non-duplicates here
for key in list(data.keys()):  # note need to take a copy of the keys
    if len(data[key]) == 1:  # only one value in the list
        del data[key]

print(dict(data))

>>> {"xxa": ["aaa","bbb","ccc","hhh"], "xxf": ["fff","jjj"]}
```

or if you prefer a non-destructive approach to finding duplicates:

```py
def _filter_duplicates(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if len(value) > 1:
            yield key, value

def find_duplicates(data):
    return dict(_filter_duplicates(data))

print(find_duplicates(data))

>>> {"xxa": ["aaa","bbb","ccc","hhh"], "xxf": ["fff","jjj"]}
```

Comment: Clever solution! Is there something missing from this code? Where are the entries for "xxe", "xxi" or "xxd" for example?

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to remove non-dupes after the fact - which I've added in now! Although perhaps the OP would prefer to omit this with hindsight - I'll leave that up to them!

Comment: Yes. Now, this is a more purist comment, but you don't really need the `list(data.keys())`, do you? I would think that `data.keys()` is enough.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't permitted, since the dictionary would change size during iteration (which would throw the`.keys()` iterator out of order). You need to create a copy of the keys, and `list` is one such way, although there may be a less costly way of doing so using generators

Comment: For posterity, I've added in one such mechanism