# how to view excel file in browser using Spring MVC and jsp java javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, jsp, apache-poi

[image]

This is the project structure. I want to display an excel file on a JSP page so that the user can edit and save it. It is very helpful to use all the excel formulas and logic.

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: I want to find way to show excel in our web project in jsp page

Comment: Still, what is the issue?

Comment: I don't know what is way to show excel in jsp page?

Comment: Did you try anything? Sounds to me like you want a full fletched excel viewer/editor online. That is not really feasible and way exceeds any possible question on SO

Comment: I did not get any code to view excel in jsp. I find something lib like OpenXML4J  java library .That is use to creation and manipulation Word, Excel and PowerPoint documents.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would read the excel file row by row. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file).

Afterwards, you parse the rows into an HTML table and will be able to render it.

Comment: No I want to open excel as it is in jsp page . Is it possible or not?

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: You could, however, create a shared file on the official web excel instance and redirect to that link.